# Delete group tab with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I want to delete a group tab using JavaScript.

I have the current tab id, and with that i get the current group tab id (if the current tab is not in a group tab it returns -1).

Now I wonder if there is something like this :

`chrome.tabs.remove(tabId)`

but for the group tab, so more like :

`chrome.tabGroups.remove(groupId)`.

Here's my code if it helps :

```
chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, async function (tabs) {
    console.log(tabs[0].id, tabs[0].groupId);
    let currentTab = tabs[0].id;
    let currentGroupId = tabs[0].groupId;

    //get all the infos about the group
    let infos = await chrome.tabGroups.get(tabs[0].groupId);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use chrome.tabs.query to find the tabs with the same groupId and then call chrome.tabs.remove with an array of these tabs' ids:

```js
async function closeGroup() {
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
  const groupTabs = await chrome.tabs.query({groupId: tab.groupId});
  await chrome.tabs.remove(groupTabs.map(t => t.id));
}
```

Comment: Oh i actually want to close all the tabs in the group. Like close definitely all the tabs inside the group, not just ungroup the tabs. My question wasn't so clear sorry :-/

Comment: See the updated answer.